# Can not format the `less` code in `.vue` file exactly in WebStorm

Tags: vue.js, less, webstorm

Use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> can not format the `less` code in `.vue` file exactly in WebStorm.

[image]

You see the upper snapshot, it will format like the `css`.the `.tag-model-mask` block code should indent more 2 spaces.

The bellow is the settings of indent, I also don't think this affect the `.vue` file.

[image]

Comment: Looks as if code is not treated as less, it's parsed as CSS (note the red highlighting that indicates syntax errors). What WebStorm version do you use? using `rel="stylesheet/less"` is not required in recent versions

Comment: I use the `2016.2`

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading to the most recent version - Vue support is much-much better there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afterwards I found the solution:

First config the `Preferences`-> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Less`,  I have done this:

[image]

Second, add the `rel="stylesheet/less"` property to the `<script>`：

```
<style lang="less" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

then format the file it will works.